# Powershell PSPKI module is not working in azure automation account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, powershell-module

I've imported PSPKI modules in to azure automation account, when using the cmdlets of PSPKI I always get command not recognized. I could see the module is installed successfully and could see the cmdlets in my runbook, but somehow the cmdlets are not recognized.

for example **Test-WebServerSSL** -URL login.live.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, to fix the issue, run `Import-Module -Name PSPKI` first.

```
Import-Module -Name PSPKI
Test-WebServerSSL -URL login.live.com
```

[image]